# AJAX Flask POST sending same data to all clients

Tags: python, ajax, flask, real-time

I'm getting countdown time data successfully but when more than one client connects to the server, the data does not look the same for everyone. (The timer breaks down and starts skipping multiple times per second.)

How do I ensure that constantly updated data send to all clients in the same way?

My Flask route.

```
@app.route("/countdown",methods=["POST"])
def countdown():
    countdown_second = int(get_db()["countdown"]) # get countdown second from db
    delta_t = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=countdown_second))

    change_countdown_time(countdown_second-1) #write new countdown second to db
    
    return jsonify(delta_t),200
```

My AJAX call.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
     setInterval(function () {GET_countdown()}, 1000);
 });


function GET_countdown() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/countdown",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#countdown").html(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your countdown is reliant on the client (your javascript) POSTing to countdown every second. The problem is that this will occur once per second for each client. Hence it works with 1 client but not multiple.

A better way to do it is for your server to be responsible for the countdown. How you might do that is to store a `datetime` in your database that corresponds to 0. Then with each POST it calculates the seconds based on the current time.

```
@app.route("/countdown")
def countdown():

    # You might have to change things with your db to get this to work, but here is the concept.
    countdown_datetime = get_db()["countdown"] # get datetime when countdown is 0

    delta_t = (datetime.now() - countdown_datetime).total_seconds()
        
    return jsonify(delta_t),200
```

Also not I changed it from a POST to a GET since this endpoint no longer changes values, it only reports them.